# Comparing various ways to move a game actor having time-dependent velocity

Tags: comparison, computer-games

Assume I have a game actor (name it `MyActor` for further references) to be moved up and down according to $z=f(t)=A\sin \omega t$ (or any non constant velocity). The game engine provides us with

- callable `GetGameTimeSinceCreation()` to obtain the age of the actor.
- overridable `Tick(float DeltaTime)` in which we put our code to move the actor.

Note that if we invoke `GetGameTimeSinceCreation()` in `Tick(float DeltaTime)` as follows

```
void MyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
   float PreviousAge = GetGameTimeSinceCreation() - DeltaTime;
}
```

`GetGameTimeSinceCreation()` called in the **current** tick is equal to  `GetGameTimeSinceCreation()` called in the **previous** tick plus `DeltaTime` called in the **current** tick.

I found there are 3 ways to move the actor:

#### Case 1: Only use $z=f(t)$

```
void MyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
   float T = GetGameTimeSinceCreation();
   Location.Z = A*Sin(W*T);
}
```

#### Case 2: Use $z(t)=z(t-\Delta t) + f'(t) \,\Delta t$

\begin{align}
z(t) 
&= z(t-\Delta t) + \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{f(t)-f(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}\,\Delta t\\
&= z(t-\Delta t) + f'(t) \, \Delta t
\end{align}

```
void MyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
   float T = GetGameTimeSinceCreation();
   Location.Z += A*W*Cos(W*T)*DeltaTime;
}
```

#### Case 3: Use $z(t)=z(t-\Delta t) + f(t)-f(t-\Delta t)$

\begin{align}
z(t) 
&= z(t-\Delta t) + \frac{f(t)-f(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}\Delta t\\
&= z(t-\Delta t) + f(t)-f(t-\Delta t)
\end{align}

```
void MyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
   float T = GetGameTimeSinceCreation();
   Location.Z += A*(Sin(W*T)-Sin(W*(T-DeltaTime)));
}
```

#### Question

In my opinion:

- Case 1 is accurate and needs least computations.
- Case 2 is approximation but needs less computations compared to Case 3.
- Case 3 is approximation and needs more computations.

I am wondering why there are still game developers using Case 3, for example, [in this tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/CPPProgrammingQuickStart/) (please proceed to the end of Step 3 to see the relevant code).

I want to know the differences between them from computer scientist's perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any general answer -- I expect it might depends on the circumstances.  In the specific situation you mentioned, for the specific choice of $f$ you mention, Case 1 seems better to me, if we ignore the computation time.  Cases 2 and 3 might suffer from accumulated roundoff error.  For some functions, Case 2 might be faster.

But who knows?  I could imagine in some applications there could be other considerations that are not apparent here, or that vary depending on the specific usage.